# Latitude Longitude IOS 4.3

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I´m following the http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/getting-your-location-in-an-iphone-application tutorial, but I can´t not get mi latitude and longitude in my Xcode SDK.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

int degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
double decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
int minutes = decimal * 60;
double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                 degrees, minutes, seconds];
//latLabel.text = lat;
degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - degrees);
minutes = decimal * 60;
seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
NSString *longt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                   degrees, minutes, seconds];  
NSLog(@"%@ %@",longt, lat);

}
```

It don´t show me the latitude and longitude in the Console.
Help me please.

Comment: Are you implementing the delegate method `locationManager:didFailWithError:`? If so, is there an error? If not, implement it and see if there's an error.

Comment: The code works straight of the bat for me. In a single view app. Did you click the OK when the app asked to use your current location?

Comment: Ah, I just realised I was using iOS5.  Are you getting : server did not accept client registration 68. in the consol

Comment: Yes I click OK when the app asked to use your current location

Comment: Are you getting : server did not accept client registration 68 in the console

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. If it does not work - the issue is not here.

Make sure:

1. You running it on a device (not emulator)
2. Your device has SIM installed and connected to cellular network
3. It's very good idea to have the device connected to WiFi with Internet access.

All these things will help GPS to fix the position faster using assisted GPS.

Also, take into account that Core Location returns last known position almost immediately. It's stale and may be wrong, but provided immediately. If do not getting anything at all - it looks like the issue with Core Location on your device, not with the application.

Also, it's good idea to implement locationManager:didFailWithError: method to catch possible errors. Like disabled GPS.

Here is example for this method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"GPS Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

GPS position fixing may take few minutes for 3Gs and early, and about 10 seconds for 4 and 4S (assuming clear sky view in both cases)

Comment: The Log show me these error: Error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"  Any idea??